# Can I reduce the power used by an AC heater?

Tags: power, appliances, heater

I have a 2000W resistive heater that plugs into 220V AC. Is there any device that I can place between the heater and the outlet that will make it, simply speaking, not heat as much, and behave as it's a 1000W heater?

I would also like to maintain the output fairly constant, so not like a timer plug that turns it off every other minute.

My intuition tells me that probably not, because then more heaters would have a function like that built in. It seems that those that do just have multiple coils that can be controlled separately.

Comment: A transformer 220/155 would do the thing if it was just a coil. But the heater has probably some controller or protection that will prevent it from working under lower voltage.

Comment: @AlexVB what if it's spliced in right before the coil?

Comment: This means you are building your own heater from parts. Please consider the risks. Basically, heat produced by a resistor depend on voltage squared. So something like this https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07M8Z8WTJ (but with 220 V input) will allow you to build a regulated heater.

Comment: Get yourself a dimmer capable of 2 kW and just dial it back a bit.

Comment: What is bad with simple thermostat? It can maintain constant temperature in room according the setpoint you choose.

Comment: Does it have a fan?

Comment: Does it have a replaceable element, and, if so, are replacements available rated at 1000 W?

Comment: @MichalPodmanický, it would be sometimes useful to run the heater at half power, in case the thermostat decides to turn on when there are several other appliances running. I don't want to turn it off altogether, just allow for some headroom during certain times of the day. The real solution would be to upgrade to a higher amperage tier with my provider, but it's a rare enough situation that I'd rather just have a switch for it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, at that point I might as well just buy a second heater.

Comment: @Jeroen3 no fan, analog thermostat. I figure if it had any sort of electronics, messing with the voltage would be a bad idea.

Comment: @AlexJ if there is no fan you can use a dimmer, try searching "garden heater dimmer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing a diode in one mains lead will provide half power. This causes energy to flow on only one half cycle per power cycle and causes waveform distortion. It may or may not be illegal where you are. If everyone did this it would cause problems. A few people doing it will probably have minimal effect overall.

A diode used in this way should be rated at at least 10 A, and higher is better. Voltage rating should be at least 500 V and higher is better. Power dissipated in the diode will be about 5 watt (1 V X 10 A X 50%).

A more approved approach is to use a 2 kW or higher rated phase controlled "dimmer". This produces equally nasty distortion on each half cycle :-).

Best of all is a PWM controlled full bridge dimmer (usually MOSFET or IGBT) but these are less common. Either one is not overly hard for DIY construction.

---

General stack-exchange example of a PWM controlled full wave dimmer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/394635/3288)

Circuit from Spehro's above answer

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzH81a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Switching 1000 W with a diode may cause problems with devices sensitive to voltage qualty  in your own home. I once got LED lamp blinking after powering on a heater with switching power supply (it might be not best quality lamp, but nevertheless).

Comment: @AlexVB yes, it's possible. You'd hope that modern electronic devices would be immune to that. Your lamp indicates that that is not always the case.

Answer (score 2):

There are several devices that do exactly what you want, and some that come close.

Power controllers do exist for that range of heater power, though they switch on and off with a cycle of seconds. With the time constant of the heater, that's more or less constant output. There is no standard though, and you'd have to check the specifications for any type before you bought it.

A series resistor would reduce the power, but would get very hot. Interestingly a second identical 2 kW heater would halve the voltage and current to your first heater, reducing its output to 500 W. The 500 W given off by the 'dropper' heater would bring the total power dissipation to 1 kW.

An autotransformer will reduce the voltage and current it operates at. For 1 kW though, it would be big, heavy and expensive.

A series inductor or series capacitor will reduce the voltage , current and power factor it operates at, without itself getting hot. For 1 kW though, it would be big, heavy and expensive. Its reactance would be equal to the roughly 30 Ω of your heater to halve its output power, so 100 mH (fluorescent ballasts in parallel) or 100 uF (some motor-run capacitors in parallel)

A series diode will halve the power, though the resulting DC load is not nice for your supplier's AC distribution equipment, and may not be permitted depending on where you are.

A phase-shift controller would chop every mains half-cycle to give effectively continuous output. However, those available to domestic buyers are usually for small loads like room lights and are rarely rated above a few hundred watts. Theatre lighting controllers can be had in that rating though.

Comment: Ah yes, DMX dimmers for PAR lights! Would something like that work on a heater? With the added bonus of being remote controllable!

Answer (score 1):

This is how was done in old days:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2febLui.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This was used in all hair driers, kitchen ovens, ...etc. I do think it is still in use today.

But it has a drawback: It may cause saturation in transformers, chokes, ... connected on mains. If the mains impedance is quite large - if you do live at several distance from distribution transformer, then it will cause a small DC component on your mains. This small DC voltage would cause a transformer to heat more and to be biased, thus may enter into saturation. Many audiophiles do put special DC block filters on their HiFi to overcome this. But I had never had a such issue.